# Why was this comment flag rejected?

Tags: discussion, flagging, comments

I marked [this comment](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/137174/is-kalara-formerly-starfleet#comment346737_137174) as ***'obsolete'*** since it related to the *future* release of a film, but one that is now released.

> *I don't think this can be confirmed until the film is released on
>   streaming or home video, but some online sources are claiming that the
>   photos of Franklin crew members Jessica Wolff and Anderson Le are
>   identifiable as Kalara and Manas. I supposed they may be recognizable
>   as the actors' real human faces? If so, that's a neat easter egg.*

At best it seems to be an *answer in comment form* but it's certainly outdated (superseded by events and [my answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/137436/20774)) and hence no longer serves a useful purpose.

**Why was it rejected by a moderator?**

Comment: I can't say why it was rejected, but I'm fairly sure that the purpose of the "obsolete" flag is not outdated information in comments. It's comments that reference aspects of the question or answers that no longer apply (edited, accepted, etc.) or that are irrelevant once a single user has seen them.

Comment: *obsolete comments are those which served a purpose once upon a time but no longer*. This comment once served the purpose which it no longer does.

Comment: @Edlothiad - I'd be rather cautious about deleting comments simply for referencing out-of-date information in the real world, or (particularly) for being "superseded" by an answer.

Comment: you should never be cautious about deleting comments. Comments exist to be deleted.

Comment: @KutuluMike - Hence my surprise. Out of 1000+ flags I've raised, I've only had a couple declined and I can't remember the last time I got a rejection on an obsolete flag.

Comment: @KutuluMike - They are meant to be more ephemeral than answers, true. That doesn't mean that we don't have specific comment flag reasons with specific purposes. Nor that we don't need a reason to delete comments (as you seem to be saying?)

Comment: @Adamant we _don't_ need a reason to delete comments. That's the point.

Comment: If that were true, there would be no need for flag reasons. ;)

Comment: there isn't a _need_ for comment flags reason. They're just convenient.

Comment: Follow-up question: why is one rejected comment flag worth a whole meta post? :-)

Comment: @Randal'Thor - Because I didn't understand why it had been rejected and because it's such a rarity for it to happen

Comment: @Randal'Thor: Follow-up follow-up question: why is one misunderstood or confusing thing worth a whole meta post? Possible answer: because that's what meta is for.